# Service returns a null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-service

I created a service to get data from the /proc/meminfo and the service class is :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MonitorService extends Service{

Vector<String> memFree, buffers, cached, active, inactive, swapTotal,dirty;
int TOTAL_INTERVALS = 440;
private BufferedReader readStream;
private String x;
int memTotal;

private Runnable readRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        read(); // We call here read() because to draw the graphic we need
                // at less 2 read values.
        while (readThread == Thread.currentThread()) {
            try {
                read();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

private Thread readThread = new Thread(readRunnable, "readThread");

class MyServiceDataBinder extends Binder {
    MonitorService getService() {
        return MonitorService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    memFree = new Vector<String>(this.TOTAL_INTERVALS);
    buffers = new Vector<String>(this.TOTAL_INTERVALS);
    cached = new Vector<String>(this.TOTAL_INTERVALS);
    active = new Vector<String>(this.TOTAL_INTERVALS);
    inactive = new Vector<String>(this.TOTAL_INTERVALS);
    swapTotal = new Vector<String>(this.TOTAL_INTERVALS);
    dirty = new Vector<String>(this.TOTAL_INTERVALS);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new MyServiceDataBinder();
}

private void read() {
    try {
        readStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/meminfo"));
        x = readStream.readLine();
        while (x != null) {

            /*
             * When the limit TOTAL_INTERVALS is surpassed by some vector we
             * have to remove all the surpassed elements because, if not,
             * the capacity of the vector will be increase x2.
             */
            while (memFree.size() >= this.TOTAL_INTERVALS)
                memFree.remove(memFree.size() - 1);
            while (buffers.size() >= this.TOTAL_INTERVALS)
                buffers.remove(buffers.size() - 1);
            while (cached.size() >= this.TOTAL_INTERVALS)
                cached.remove(cached.size() - 1);
            while (active.size() >= this.TOTAL_INTERVALS)
                active.remove(active.size() - 1);
            while (inactive.size() >= this.TOTAL_INTERVALS)
                inactive.remove(inactive.size() - 1);
            while (swapTotal.size() >= this.TOTAL_INTERVALS)
                swapTotal.remove(swapTotal.size() - 1);
            while (dirty.size() >= this.TOTAL_INTERVALS)
                dirty.remove(dirty.size() - 1);

            // We read the memory values. The percents are calculated in the
            // AnotherMonitor class.
            if (x.startsWith("MemTotal:"))
                memTotal = Integer.parseInt(x.split("[ ]+", 3)[1]);
            if (x.startsWith("MemFree:"))
                memFree.add(0, x.split("[ ]+", 3)[1]);
            if (x.startsWith("Buffers:"))
                buffers.add(0, x.split("[ ]+", 3)[1]);
            if (x.startsWith("Cached:"))
                cached.add(0, x.split("[ ]+", 3)[1]);
            if (x.startsWith("Active:"))
                active.add(0, x.split("[ ]+", 3)[1]);
            if (x.startsWith("Inactive:"))
                inactive.add(0, x.split("[ ]+", 3)[1]);
            if (x.startsWith("SwapTotal:"))
                swapTotal.add(0, x.split("[ ]+", 3)[1]);
            if (x.startsWith("Dirty:"))
                dirty.add(0, x.split("[ ]+", 3)[1]);
            x = readStream.readLine();
        }

        readStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The class where I call the created service :

```
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
 import java.util.Vector;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.ComponentName;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.ServiceConnection;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.os.IBinder;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.sliit.droidman.R;

 public class Processor extends Activity{

private TextView ram1, ram2, ram3, ram4, ram5, ram6, ram7;
private MonitorService MyMonitor;
private DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,###,##0");
private Handler myHandler;

private Runnable drawRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        setTextLabel(ram1,MyMonitor.memFree);
        setTextLabel(ram2,MyMonitor.buffers);
        setTextLabel(ram3,MyMonitor.cached);
        setTextLabel(ram4,MyMonitor.active);
        setTextLabel(ram5,MyMonitor.inactive);
        setTextLabel(ram6,MyMonitor.swapTotal);
        setTextLabel(ram7,MyMonitor.dirty);

        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

private ServiceConnection MyService = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyMonitor = null;
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyMonitor = ((MonitorService.MyServiceDataBinder)service).getService();
        ram1.setText(myFormat.format(MyMonitor.memTotal) + " kB");
        myHandler.post(drawRunnable); <--- A null pointer Exceprtion occurs
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startService(new Intent(this, MonitorService.class));
    setContentView(R.layout.resources_processor);

    ram1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Appres_ProcessorInfo1);
    ram2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Appres_ProcessorInfo2);
    ram3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Appres_ProcessorInfo3);
    ram4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Appres_ProcessorInfo4);
    ram5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Appres_ProcessorInfo5);
    ram6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Appres_ProcessorInfo6);
    ram7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Appres_ProcessorInfo7);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    bindService(new Intent(this, MonitorService.class), MyService, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    unbindService(MyService);
}

private void setTextLabel(TextView textView, Vector<String> y) {
        if (!y.isEmpty()) {
            textView.setText(myFormat.format(Integer.parseInt(y.firstElement())) + " kB");
            //textViewP.setText(myFormatPercent.format(Integer.parseInt(y.firstElement())* 100 / (float) myAnReaderService.memTotal) + "%");
        } else
            textView.setText("Value");
}

 }
```

The log cat out put :

```
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.sliit.droidman.systemresources.Processor$2.onServiceConnected(Processor.java:49)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1097)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1114)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-13 10:20:08.109: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 10:20:15.860: E/Trace(764): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

I get a null pointer exception from the code that I have pointed out in the code. Please help me out to figure out the error that i DO in this section.

thank you.

Comment: You have not instantiated your `myHandler` any where in your code.. change that and then update the code and error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
 private Thread readThread = new Thread(readRunnable, "readThread");
```

You create this thread in service, but never start/call it. That is the reason your vectors are empty. Try starting it in onBind().